# How to check and match the possible combinations of arraylist elements

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

```
String [] A = {"High","Medium","Low"};
String [] B = {"High","Medium","Low"};
String [] C = {"High","Medium","Low"};
String [] D = {"High","Medium","Low"};
String [] E = {"High","Medium","Low"};
String [] F = {"High","Medium","Low"};

JComboBox Ai = new JComboBox(A); JComboBox Bi = new JComboBox(B);
JComboBox Ci = new JComboBox(C); JComboBox Di = new JComboBox(C);
JComboBox Ei = new JComboBox(E); JComboBox Fi = new JComboBox(F);

....

//add the user choice in arrayList
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add((String) Ai.getSelectedItem());
a.add((String) Bi.getSelectedItem());
a.add((String) Ci.getSelectedItem());
a.add((String) Di.getSelectedItem());
a.add((String) Ei.getSelectedItem());
a.add((String) Fi.getSelectedItem());
```

EDITED:
Scenario:
There are 6 groups (Ai,Bi,Ci,Di,Ei,Fi) of choice. On each group, there are 3 sub choice (High(H),Medium(M),Low(L)).The user need to choose one on each of the 6 groups

The choice could be e.g. "HHHLLL" or "MMMLLM" or "HHLLMM" etc.

What is the best way to check and match the user choice without writing many `else if` ?
e.g.

```
if(Ai=="High" && Bi=="High" && Ci=="Low" && Di=="High" && Ei=="Low" && Fi=="Medium") {
    System.out.println("Good Choice"); 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there are 3^6 not 6! permutations.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If you have 6 combo boxes with 3 choices each then your number of combinations is 3^6, not 6!.  What is your criteria for determining whether a given set of inputs are valid?

Comment: @Cletus:  damn it, give a guy a chance to type

Comment: I'm curios about cases you wanna check. Do you have 18 different pieces of stuff to do with ? or there is only several possible ways?

Comment: @ at one time I only compare 6 not 18

Comment: Where does the 18 come from? 18 valid combinations and the remaining 3^6 - 18 = 711 invalid ones? If you want to check whether one of the "good 18" was selected, you can create a Set with all the "good" series of initials: "HHLHLM", ...; if an answer's initials are in the set, the answer is good. Just stop using an ArrayList and append the initials to a string (or StringBuilder) instead.

But I still do not understand the initial question.

Comment: tucuxi@ yes, the possible combination is like e.g."HHLHLM", "HHHHHH", "MMMLLL" etc. according to the user's choice. How can I check this choice without writing the "if" or "if else"

Comment: Why is this tagged recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need to give a new list of choices to each JComboBox.

```
String[] choices = {"High", "Medium", "Low"};

JComboBox ai = new JComboBox(choices);
JComboBox bi = new JComboBox(choices);
JComboBox ci = new JComboBox(choices);
JComboBox di = new JComboBox(choices);
JComboBox ei = new JComboBox(choices);
JComboBox fi = new JComboBox(choices);
```

(Variables in Java usually start with a lowercase letter, so I changed the variable names to lowercase.)

---

Next, you can put all six JComboBoxes in an array. You'll see why this is useful in a moment.

```
JComboBox[] boxes = {ai, bi, ci, di, ei, fi};
```

---

Now, you can make your user choice string like this:

```
// Create an ArrayList of Strings, where each string is either "H", "M", or "L"
ArrayList<String> userChoice = new ArrayList<String>()

for (JComboBox box : boxes) {
    // Go through this code once for each JComboBox in boxes
    // The first time through, "box" means the first JComboBox
    // The second time through, "box" is the second JComboBox, etc.
    if (box.getValue().equals("High")) {
         userChoice.add("H");
    } else if (box.getValue().equals("Medium")) {
         userChoice.add("M");
    } else if (box.getValue().equals("Low")) {
         userChoice.add("L")
    }
}
```

That for-each loop might not be familiar to you. It means "go through this code once for each *something* in *array of somethings*."

---

If you use this code, you'll end up with an ArrayList called userChoice that has something like ["H", "H", "M", "M", "L", "L"].

Comment: Thank you. What is the different with "append" and "add" ?

Comment: add is on ArrayList, append is on JComboBox. Two completely different classes. Isn't it obvious? :) They both add stuff to the end of their respective lists of data (although add is from a collections base type, so works differently on different types of collection as its implemented differently -- i.e., Set)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Jessy - that was a mistake on my part. ArrayList has an "add" method; it does NOT have an "append" method. I've edited the answer so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assign integer to each choice and compute some evaluation function of use choice.

For instance: `Ai * 3^0 + Bi * 3^1 + ... + Fi * 3^5`

Then you would have user choice mapped to certain integer interval  and could do something with it easier.

But, what do you actually want to do with it?

Comment: easier to just append all answers in a canonical order to a string. That way there is no possible int overflow if the number of questions grows to a few dozen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use an `enum` to represent the 3 choices. The `==` (that you used on strings) is safe on enum constants, because they're guaranteed to be singletons. An `enum` constant can be converted to and from strings easily (`toString` and `valueOf`).

So now you have 6 variables, and each can have one of 3 values, so there are 3^6 possible scenarios. What's the best way to handle them?

In the most general case, you have to be prepared to handle all 3^6 values independently of each other. That is, I'm assuming you're not doing grouped handling like "as long as there's more Highs than Lows, do X".

I recommend using a `Map` to map a setting combination to an action object.

```
enum Setting {
   High, Medium, Low;
}

class SettingCombination {
  List<Setting> combo = ...;
  // should be immutable, with proper equals and hashCode @Override
  // should also have named getters for each of the 6 settings
}

interface SettingCombinationHandler {
   void handle(SettingCombination settings);      
}

class SettingCombinationHandlingService {
   Map<SettingCombination, SettingCombinationHandler> handlers = ...;
   // perhaps provide a default handler as well
}
```

The idea is that for each valid combination, you map a specific handler for it. The mapping need not be one-to-one -- several combinations can be mapped to the same handler if this suits your need (the actual combination is passed as parameter to `handle` so it can differentiate them if it needs to).

Now, note that I haven't even addressed how you're going to display these setting options in the `JComboBox` or whatever else you may be using. This is intentional. You should separate your business logic from your UI; your data model from your view model.